# Drupal 7 - Blocks won't preserve order

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I seem to be having a problem with the ordering of blocks in Drupal. I have gone to *Structure > Blocks> Theme* where *Theme* is the name of the current theme.

In the content section of this admin area I have: *Content* and *View: Homepage Featured: Homepage Featured Block*.

The content is supposed to sit ontop of the view, which in this admin area it is. But when it's displayed, the order is reversed and I'm unable to change no matter how I have the order.

The node template issues the following statement:

```
<?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

Any ideas? Is there something in the view that's doing this? **Thanks in advance for your help!!**

Answer (score 3):

Figured this out -- if you go into the *Main page content* block and edit the visibility settings for the "Pages" tab it fixes this.

I listed the pages in the textbox and checked the "Only the listed pages" and viola.

Comment: I have done it backward. (i.e) I have checked "All pages except those listed" and click "Save block". It works well. Hence, any changes in "Pages" tab will reset to correct order while render the blocks.